# Isn't supplying three phase power to regular retail customers UNSTABLE?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Some countries, outside the US, supply 3-Phase power direct to individual apartments (aka "flats") in highrise towers. *[ Especially former UK colonies and the like, and also noted on this thread in some cases in US too:* [Why do I have three phase electricity?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30147/why-do-i-have-three-phase-electricity) ].

Isn't this a very wrong thing to do from the point of view of **stability of the grid supply**, because the currents in the phases will be **unbalanced**, compared to running proper 3-phase equipment/loads which automatically balance the phases? After all, what is the individual apartment dweller supposed to do with each phase? All his/her appliances run on single phase. Balancing the phases would be nigh  impossible, precluding, of course, a wye-delta transformer for the whole apartment or house (let's ignore that possibility)!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Imbalances on alternating current  due to reactance can easily be rectified with capacitors. It's not as big of a problem as you may think.

Comment: This might be a good question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think a problem with the Ops question is he/she doesn't indicate which imbalances they're referring to. I.e.,  imbalance from overloading a phase? Imbalance from reactance?

Answer (score 5):

- In the USA, a small block shares a 240V split-phase transformer.  The primary of that transformer is on typically 2400 volt 3-phase delta, one leg obviously.   The next block over is tapped off different phases.
- In Europe, a neighborhood gets a 415V 3-phase wye transformer, and the first house is connected to phase A and neutral, next house to B and neutral, next house to C and neutral, etc.  Some houses get 2 or 3 phases, particularly if they are load-heavy.  It's as simple as delivering one more wire.  They can then connect appliances to 415V, but that is rare except for serious tradesmen or hobbyists with industrial tools.
- In Manhattan, a block gets 208V 3-phase wye, house 1 gets phase A and B and neutral, house 2 gets B, C and neutral, house 3 gets A and C etc.
- Distant rural America often sees ~10kv single-phase with a transformer at each farmhouse. However this is one side of 3-phase delta, the next farm road will be tapped on the next phase.
- Australia sometimes distributes at high voltage with a single wire and earth as neutral, literally one solitary wire on the pole.  It is 3-phase "wye" with the other 2 phases going down other distribution lines.

All distribution is 3-phase - if not to the pole, at least to the neighborhood.

So what choice do you have? Nobody is seriously going to run a big single-phase distribution system**, and do a large conversion from 3-phase to 1-phase, simply over imbalance.

### It averages out

Imbalances aren't as big a deal as you might think.  With a sufficiently large number of houses to average over, eventually load per phase averages out.

If for some reason it doesn't, the power company can change which phase a particular flat or block is tapping.

Now if the town's large industry decides to heavily load one phase and create an imbalance, then they might get a serious talking-to by the power company.  Because they are big enough to create an imbalance too big to average out.

---

** Except the railroad.  Look on Amtrak's Northeast Corridor, see the *even* number of power lines?  Single phase.  They have to solve the "how do you put an enormous single-phase load on 3-phase" problem.

Comment: Re Europe: it varies. In the UK it will be as you describe but in France, Germany, Spain etc. 3-phase going to individual houses/apartments is normal.

Comment: @Niall I had actually put that in the first draft, but elided it for simplicity and out of concern it would confound the matter and seem unbelievable to Americans.   So I added it back and added an unbelievable bit about Aussies :)

Comment: this isn't important as your answer does a great job at answering the question. For completeness, it's normal in many countries to have 3-phase going to every house in an area and every apartment in a building, by design. In practice the heavier load items(heating, a/c,  heat-pumps, maybe ovens and dryers) will be 3-phase and then (often, not always) each phase will have a number of rooms on it.

Answer (score 2):

### Panels are self-balancing to a degree

Roughly balancing the phases on a 3 phase wye system servicing single phase loads is assured by *panelboard design and installation* -- panelboard slots in a three phase panelboard are arrayed ABCABCABC going down a column, akin to the ABABAB layout of a modern split phase panel.  This means that simply shoving single phase circuits into the first slots you find will get you a layout that is reasonably sensibly balanced.  Heavy two-phase loads are a bit more of a consternation, but work out OK in the end, in particular because range loads don't pull their full load much of the time (how many times are you running the broiler and all four surface elements full blast on an electric range?).

Keep in mind that it's actually possible to get imbalance between the legs in a pathologically configured single phase panel as well, but it almost *never* happens in real life because shoving single phase breakers into the panel pretty much *can't* yield such pathologies unless you do something bizarre like put all the lighting on one leg and all the small appliances on the other.

### High power loads in 230/415Y countries are 3 phase to begin with

In many areas where the European (230/415Y) system is in use, range and other such heavy loads are fed from all three phases.  This elimiates the phase balance issues caused by asymmetric two phase loads on a three phase system, of course.

### Commercial buildings have this too

Most commercial buildings use three-phase power due to the heavier motor loads present in commercial and industrial work compared to dwellings.  As a result, the lighting and receptacles in these buildings are fed as single phase loads from the three phase service instead of drawing a separate single phase service, bringing you to the same point as you find in residences fed with three phase.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is if the loads are connected and balanced there is no problem. Even using only single phase loads on a 3 phase panel is ok but they do need to be balanced. When I say balanced each phase is drawing a similar amount of current. If there are large imbalances in the load with 3 phase (and single phase "split" used in most U.S. homes) the imbalance can cause the neutral to "float" I have seen imbalances cause up to 7vac swings in the neutral (above 2.5v switching power supplies tend to cave problems or I have observed this). I have been able to reduce or eliminate floating neutrals by making sure each phase / leg is drawing a similar amount of power. How much imbalance will it take to cause a problem? At the local level or house it depends on the size of the transformer that is being used. A smaller transformer requires the legs to be more closely balanced some homes can handle 50 amp imbalance with no ill effects while others cannot. Now we get to the grid level. Each area is tapped and the loads are balanced reducing stress on the system. Last 3 phase power consumers are charged a extra fee for power imbalance. Most of the time this comes as a power shift due to the use of large or many induction motors the power company has to correct for the imbalance so they charge more (or the customer adds capacitor banks to correct the imbalance and reduce there bill). So is it making the system unstable with an imbalance? No the problems with imbalance are usually localized and the power company adjusts connections and phasing lead/lag to adjust for loads (on top of charging much more for the imbalanced power).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Industrial and commercial customers have many single phase loads. All we do is balance the loads.

When you have 12 circuits of office lighting that is all single phase then 4 complete 3 phase circuits are balanced.

If one of the phases is over or under loaded you just rebalance the circuits to compensate.

It is not actually a problem.

Happy day!

Answer (score 0):

You are partially right: there is the possibility that the phases are not used in a balanced way.

But if you have a 3 phase system, you usually have 5 conductors: L1, L2, L3, N and PE. N is neutral and PE is Protection Earth.

If you imagine the three L[123] being the nodes of a balanced triangle (in terms of complex voltages with radius and phases), the N normally sits in the middle of the triangle. If you are absolutely equally balanced, there is no current in the N. If you are only partially balanced, you have a residual current in the N which compensates the unbalancedness.

In most cases (TN topology), the N is grounded and connected to PE (Protection Earth) at the very first possible point in the house. But there is also the possibility that you have a TT topology: the N is not grounded and is able to float as it draws a lot of current. This is mostly the case if you have very few houses at the end of a transformer.

This describes the situation in Europe, particularly in Germany.